# I wanted to undelete a soft deleted item in Informatica Product 360(PIM)

Tags: informatica

I deleted an item in PIM rich client master catlog and want to get it back in master catlog like all other existing items.

I have tried modifying the deleteion timestamp for the corresponding entries for the item in ArticleRevision , Articledetail , ArticleLog tables to 31/12/9999 and the deletionuserid column to null which is essentially the deletion date , user id for all active (not deleted ) items  . This makes the item reappear in rich client however any operation on the item throws an error that object is deleted.